# python: failing in computing floating numbers

Tags: python, math, floating-point, algebra

I don't know where I fail in my approach. I got a simple formula:

`y = a/(b*c)`

with the values

`a = 4.716380460979026e-06`
`b = 0.001849764416795974`
`c = 5.6596565531748315e-05`

my code is:

```
a = 4.71628e-06
b = 0.00184
c = 5.65965e-05
y = a/(b*c)
print y
```

when calcuating this 'by hand' with a calculator i get ~166.

python prints:

`>>> 45.050781914`

can anyone help?

Comment: You're screwing up the calculation by hand. 47 / (18 * 56) ~= 0.0466

Comment: note that one is e^-5 and the other is e^-6

Comment: Doesn't matter. My result is almost exactly orders of magnitude off. Yours isn't even close.

Comment: you got a point there.. still i wonder why my python result is off as well?

Comment: Your Python result is fine.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong base in your calculations. `x`e`y` isn't `x`*e*<sup>`y`</sup>, it's `x`**10**<sup>`y`</sup>.

4.716e<sup>−6</sup> / (0.00184 * 5.65965e<sup>−5</sup>) ~= 166.59882

Comment: can you go more into the details please?

Comment: *e* is the natural number, 2.71whatever. Scientific notation is used to bring very large or very small numbers to a more reasonable representation by shifting the decimal point, which involves powers of 10. Scientific notation uses "e" or "E", but it is not related to *e*.

Answer (score 2):

You must entered something wrong in your calculator.

Google agrees with python:

https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=4.71628e-06+%2F+(+0.00184+*+5.65965e-05+)